# How to find an object key using an variable?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What I want is that my object listen to a string that I send to my function

for example :

```
const  [object,setobject] = useState([]);
      const HandleChange = (text,field) => {
        if (Object.keys(object).length > 0){ 
          var objects = values + ',' + '{"' +field +'":' + text + '}'
        
          console.log(object[text])
          setobject(objects);
        }
        else {
          var objects = '{"' + field +'":' + '"'+ text + '"}'
          setobject(objects);
          console.log(object[field]);
        } 
      }
```

from this `object`(which is a state) I want to get if there is any value equal to `variable text` inside my object, someone knows how can I find it ?

Comment: Your `object` variable is text, so using `object[text]` doesn't make sense. Next, you seems to have `object` as global variable, yet, you overwrite it in the function with `var object`. And finally, why do you use text as object structure?

Comment: @vanowm Im building my own object because I have some conditional, and about overwrite, I typed the question wrong and I edited it , it was a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there several typos in your code (`object` or `objects`, `console.log(object[text])` or `console.log(object[field])`, ...).

What I understand is that you wish to access `object[field]`, but `object` is a `String` and not an `Object`.

Following this premise I would suggest converting it to an actual Object first, using `JSON.parse()`. Then you could check if `object[field]` already exists.